# Summing the series $\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{ja_{0}^kt}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

For a fixed $t$, I wish to find the value of,

$S = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{ja_{0}^kt}$ where it is known that $a_{0} > 1$. I tried to express $S$ as a $z$ transform of some known function,

$S = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} 1 \cdot z^{a_{0}^k}$, where $z :=  e^{jt}$, but the exponent $a_{0}^{k}$ that appears on the $z$ term is causing a problem. Can anybody please help? Even if we could get a lower bound $f(t) \leq S$, it would be sufficient for my use. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not think this is well-defined in the sense of ordinary functions. I think, if anything, this would converge in distribution and likely not to anything nice. If $a_0=1$, I think this would converge to a delta distribution.